# ALL loops crashing winforms vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, while-loop

I am trying to make a little Winforms game, it it seems as if my while loop (shown below) is halting me from progression.

```
       While (battlevalue = False)

            If (Player1Health <= 0) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Player Two Won!")
                End
            ElseIf (Player2Health <= 0) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Player One Won!")
                End
            End If
            If (Glave.Location.Y = SwAxe.Location.Y) Then
                If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Q) Then
                    Player2Health = (Player2Health - Player1Attack)
                    MessageBox.Show(Player2Health)
                End If
            End If
        End While
```

My .exe file crashes when any of my characters make a single move, the Visual studio debugger is useless in this situation, because it does not detect any "Problems," and it seems that I cannot go without the while loop, because the the playerattack will subtract the enemyhealth only once if I do not have the while. So I tried a do until loop. No luck either. In fact, every single loop I did crashed my application. I could not use an if statement, since they are not really loops, and I have the same problem as I do if I don't use a loop at all.

Please offer any solutions you may have.

VB.NET core 4.7.2

Visual studio version 16.6.0

Comment: You do realise that those `End` statements end the current process without any cleanup, right? `End` is like right-clicking on a process in Task Manager and selecting *End task*. Did you actually mean to use `Exit While` there rather than `End`?

Comment: Regardless, I'm guessing that you shouldn't have a loop at all. It's hard to say for sure with so little information but WinForms is event-driven so you should almost certainly be doing something each time a particular event is raised, not repeatedly when an event is raised once.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as jmc has commented; you should remove those `End` statements - they are certainly not what you want to do. I assume you were expecting to stop processing this code too, so you might not want to do the `(Glave.Location.Y = SwAxe.Location.Y)` bit.. One simple way of avoiding that is to make it part of the If Else chain

```
        If (Player1Health <= 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Player Two Won!")
            'End
        ElseIf (Player2Health <= 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Player One Won!")
            'End
        Else If (Glave.Location.Y = SwAxe.Location.Y) Then
            If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Q) Then
                Player2Health = (Player2Health - Player1Attack)
                MessageBox.Show(Player2Health)
            End If
        End If
    End While
```

Comment: Maybe he needs also to `return` or `Exit While` to not reach `If (Glave.Location.Y = SwAxe.Location.Y) Then....`. Just in case bud.